# No error for Coldfusion max post size

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When sending files in a form that cause my tests to exceed the ColdFusion admin 'Maximum size of post data', I do not get any sort of error response back from the server.  My browser will just hang as if it is loading forever.

I am running Apache 2.2.25 (patched for OpenSSL bug) and ColdFusion 10.  I have tried setting a file size limit in Apache, but it only works if I do not exceed the CF limit.  I have noticed that when I exceed the CF post limit, it does something to the Apache service where it takes a much longer than normal time to restart it (instead of 5 seconds it takes 20 - 30 seconds).

So, my questions are:

- Is this the natural behavior for CF10 when you exceed the Post size limit?
- Is there any ideas on how to get the CF server, Apache server, or browser to return an error message?  I am working towards an HTML5 based multi-file uploader and I would like to be able to handle this condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/582225/135433

Comment: @Miguel-F - I actually did see this post before and I believe the person has the same issue. I do see in my server logs that I'm reaching the max post size, but I'm looking for an answers to: (1) Is this the expected behavior? (2) Can I get an error message from the server so my browser does not just hang and so I don't have to rely on client side validation for this? (3) Is there a solid work around? I was able to setup an Apache limit, but if the post is over the CF limit, the browser does still hang.

Comment: In IIS 7 the server will return a 404 (which doesn't help in tracking it down either) so I wonder if perhaps it's related to a disconnected session with Tomcat in that scenario?  [This may have more info for you](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5030346) which explains what you're seeing as well as why tomcat does what it does and a hotfix in 2012 that may be the root cause of it